kubectl eks empty forbidden: User "" cannot get resource
I am trying to do kubectl logs -f deployment/<my-deployment> -n <my-namespace>
but I am getting this error:
Found 3 pods, using pod/<pod-name>
Error from server (Forbidden): pods "<pod-name>" is forbidden: User "" cannot get resource "pods/log" in API group "" in the namespace "<my-namespace>"

what am i missing?
It seams that the kubectl is getting an empty user, but when I execute this command It tells me that everything is ok, but its not:
$ kubectl auth can-i get pods/log -n <my-namespace>
yes


Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or DevOps. These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.
